# Score is not increasing

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I created a simple game in which the player collides with the enemy, and the score will increase by one. How to do it correctly?

Below is my code:

```
public class Bird : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject deathparticales;
    public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(-2, 0);
    public float range = 5;
    public int score;
    private string scoreText;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
        rigidbody2D.velocity = velocity;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - range * Random.value, transform.position.z);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { 
        // Die by being off screen
        Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        if (screenPosition.x < -10)
        {
            Die();
        }
        scoreText = "Score: " + score.ToString();
    }

    void OnGUI () 
    {
        GUI.color = Color.black;
        GUILayout.Label(scoreText);
    }

    // Die by collision
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D death)
    {
        if(death.transform.tag == "Playercollision")
        {
            score++;
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Instantiate(deathparticales,transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

    void Die()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Make sure the `Update()` method is called when you expect to me called. Make sure the code (which you didn't post here) that uses the new value of `scoreText` is actually executed after the `Update()` method executes. If you still can't figure it out, write a good code example and update this question or post a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: cant figure it out how to do it plz help me

Comment: If you can't figure out how to use the debugger, then SO may not be the best forum for you to get help. You'll need at least a decent understanding of how to use the available toolset (such as Visual Studio) before answers here will make much sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

You were trying to update the score inside everyone of those `Birds`.

---

#### Solution

You need a class whose only purpose is to handle the score.

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int score = 0;
    private static ScoreManager instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void incrementScore(int amount)
    {
        score += amount;
    }

    public static ScoreManager getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    void OnGUI () 
    {
       string scoreText = "Score: " + score.ToString();

       GUI.color = Color.black;
       GUILayout.Label(scoreText);
    }
}
```

Then every time you want to update the score you call `ScoreManager` from another class, like this:

```
ScoreManager.getInstance().incrementScore(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the code is from same script, the problem is that you are increasing the score of one instance of Bird class and then killing that instance:

```
score++;
Destroy(gameObject);
```

The `gameObject` refers to that gameobject into which this instance of Bird class is attached to.

Score variable is just public which means that every instance of Bird has their own, but you can access the variable from other scripts. If you want to have just one score variable shared with all Birds you could make the variable `static`.

But if you have multiple birds, all of them are going to call OnGUI function and draw the value to the screen. So it might be better idea to change your design and move the score to some other gameObject.